# Having issues uploading images using form data and fetch

Tags: react-native, fetch, form-data, charles-proxy

I have a React Native application that is using fetch to upload some text data and images. We recently noticed not all the images are saving on the server. Firing up Charles I found some of the images look malformed, not sure exactly why or what is causing this.

Through testing I have tried different images, the same image, etc and still seem to have this issue. In the screenshot below you can see the request and how only one image has the correct data. Im not sure what those symbols mean or why they are there..

[image: Charles response]

As you can see in the code, I am appending both images the same exact way..

```
// data is my object that contains job info, image meta info, etc..
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("sc", JSON.stringify(data));

// append call images
data.SavedImages.forEach(image => {
  if (image.meta && image.meta.uri) {
    formData.append(`image_sc_${image.ImageID}`, {
      uri: image.meta.uri,
      type: "image/jpeg",
      name: data.CallID
    });
  }
});

//append equip images
data.Equip.forEach(e => {
  e.SavedImages.forEach(image => {
    if (image.meta && image.meta.uri) {
      formData.append(`image_equip_${image.ImageID}`, {
        uri: image.meta.uri,
        type: "image/jpeg",
        name: image.EquipmentID
      });
    }
  });
});


return fetch(Api.buildURL("ServiceCallPayload"), {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData
})
```

I would expect the images to both be included in the request and in the correct format but instead its corrupted somehow.

Comment: Testing more with the same image, looks like both failed. These are the default images that come with iOS simulator, specifically the pink flowers. https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0q3w97evhtewwu/Screenshot%202019-06-12%2012.47.47.png?dl=0

Comment: Your uploaded image didn't load. Also, does the URI return just an image asset? Do you have an http response from the image we can see?

Answer (score 0):

Colleague of mine figured it out, the name property needed to have the proper file extension, otherwise it was treated as text.

```
// append call images
data.SavedImages.forEach(image => {
  if (image.meta && image.meta.uri) {
    formData.append(`image_sc_${image.ImageID}`, {
      uri: image.meta.uri,
      type: "image/jpeg",
      name: data.CallID + '.jpeg'
    });
  }
});
```